# Convert to base class in generic not work

Tags: c#, generics

I have a class:

```
[Serializable]
public class SaveObject
{
   public Dictionary<Type, List<BaseModel>> Tables { get; set; }
}
```

and a method which trying put a new list

```
public List<T> GetCollection<T>() where T : BaseModel
{
    if (saveObject.Tables == null)
        saveObject.Tables = new Dictionary<Type, List<BaseModel>>();

    List<T> repo = saveObject.Tables.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Key == typeof(T)).Value as List<T>;
    if (repo == null)
    {
        repo = new List<T>();
        saveObject.Tables.Add(typeof(T), repo);
    }

    return repo;
}
```

The problem is:
Cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<BaseModel>'

[image]

I don't understand why I cannot convert T to Base Model where I note in WHERE that T is BaseModel.

Comment: There's no inheritance relation between generic classes just because their type parameters have one. A List<Base>` is a different type from `Base<Concrete>`. Use *interfaces* instead of concrete containers

Comment: This is called [covariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance) - in `List<T>`, the T parameter isn't covariant which means that `List<Derived>` can't be used in places where `List<Base>` is. On the other hand in [IEnumerable<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=netcore-3.1)  the parameter *is* covariant. If you used `IList<T>` you wouldn't have any problems

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos [`IList<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ilist-1?view=netcore-3.1) has invariant type parameter, only `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant

Comment: How do you intend to use the contents of `saveObject.Tables` ? While the type parameters in  `List<T>` and `IList<T>` aren't covariant, the parameters in `IReadOnlyList<T>` and `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` are. You could use one of those interfaces to store data.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski `List<T>` implements other covariant interfaces though - [IReadOnlyList<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlylist-1?view=netcore-3.1) and [IReadOnlyCollection<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlycollection-1?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: @Kiro why not use `saveObject.Tables = new Dictionary<Type, List<T>>();`? Instead of `FirstOrDefault` you can use `Dictionary.TryGetValue(typeof(T),out var repo)`, eg `if(!tables.TryGetValue(typeof(T),out var repo){ tables.Add(typeof(T),new List<T>());}`